# Pass 3D dynamically allocated array into function (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have dynamically allocated a 3D array. I then assigned strings into the array. The 3D array prints out fine. But I cannot seem to find a way to pass it to a function. I have tried many variations of passing the array into the function. Below is my code, very grateful for any help.

```
//dynamically allocate 3d array
string *** array3D;
array3D = new string**[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    array3D[i] = new string*[columns];
    for(int j=0; j < columns;j++)
    {
        array3D[i][j] = new string[pages];
    }
}

//put strings from file into array
for(int k = 0; k < pages; k++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < columns;j++)
        {
            puzzleFile >> array3D[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}

// Call function
find(array3D);

// The couts are simply to verify the array passed in successfully
void find(string ***&array)
{
    cout << "in function array[0][0][0]" << array[0][0][0] << endl;
    cout << "array[1][0][2]" << array[1][0][2] << endl;
    cout << "array[1][0][2]" << array[0][2][1] << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is problem? I don't see any issue here. You are already passing to function.

Comment: I get an error, would it help if I copy and pasted the error

Comment: yes.. add your error here.

Comment: the error states: cannot declare pointer to 'std::string& {aka truct std::basic_string<char>&}

Comment: if this is o any help::: candidate are: template<class _CharT2> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_CharT2>::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> > >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, const _CharT2&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4394:5: note: template<class _IIter, class _Tp> _IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&)

Comment: It's forth noting that you don't need a return in your function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use rename function `find` with something else like `myfind`.

After discussing with OP, came to know he missed to declare function prototype. Hence updating answer.

Edit: Removed string.h include suggestion.

Comment: appreciate you looking at it, but that is included

Comment: Found the solution, you led me down the right path, thannks

Comment: What did you change to make it work?

Comment: It was dumb, but I forgot to declare my function above main

Comment: alright. so compiler was trying to link known definition of find ie std::find. Nice I could help you ;)

Comment: I'm new to this site. Is there any protocol for me to acknowledge your help for ratings or something?

Comment: `<string.h>` shouldn't be used in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the specifics of the problem, but, did you consider using something like this for your 3D array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
....
typedef std::vector<std::string>> V1d;  // define a vector of strings: 'pages'
typedef std::vector<V1d> V2d;  // define a vector of V1d: 'columns' of 'pages'
typedef std::vector<V2d> V3dS; // define a vector of V2d: 'rows' of 'columns' of 'pages'
...
void find(V3dS &a3d) {
    // access the data here as a3d[i][j][k] per page
}
...
V3dS array3D(rows, V2d(columns, V1d(pages)));  // declare your array with wanted sizes
...
puzzlefile >> array3D[i][j][k]; // Page data
...
find(array3D);  // call your function
```

This also comes with a little benefit: no need to worry about deallocating anything. The vectors will free everything when your array3D variable goes out of scope.
Just another idea you might find helpful :)